# How do I create VBA code to extract certain columns of data from excel file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a data file that has 600 columns and 14,000 rows of data. I am working on creating an excel GUI that lets you reduce this data to only the parameters you need. The parameters (headers) are in row 1.

Below are some of them:

```
Shop-Order
Unit
FPC Env Module
Sequence
Model
Cell-Start
Cell-End
Date-Start
Date-End
```

To save time selecting them each time from a filter list, I have created a .txt file that has a list of the parameters I need:

```
FPC
Model
Cell-End
Date-End
BRKPWR
FLOTRON
LCMP_L_IN_P
LCMP_RT_IN_P
INT_MNF_L_P
INT_MNF_RT_P
EXH_SET_PT
ECM_PARAM_23
ECM_PARAM_55
ECM_PWR_ADJ_ST
INCR_FUEL_DOH
```

I would like to read the list from a text file and reduce the data based upon this list. Is this possible, and if so what functions would I need to use?

Comment: You are not making it easy this way. This amount of data requires a **database**. Is there by any chance a way to use that and save yourself further pain?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This is not a script/code writing service. Reading **[ask]** would be a great way to better understand how this site works and what information we need to be able to help you. First and foremost, we need to know what you have already accomplished toward solving this on your own and where you got stuck. Sharing any VBA you have developed is important.

Comment: Microsoft has a free addition for Excel called [Power Pivot](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Power-Pivot-Add-in-a9c2c6e2-cc49-4976-a7d7-40896795d045). I think that fits nicely between the "Excel can't do the complex things I need it to do" and "I need a DBMS".

Answer (score 1):

Help to help yourself.

- Find "Record new macro" in your version of Excel.
- Close to it you find "Use relative references" - select this if it is relevant for the task at hand.
- Now click on "Record new macro" and type in a name and optionally add a keyboard shortcut for launching the macro.
- Do the steps that you need in the macro.
- Click "Stop recording".
- Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and hit <kbd>F8</kbd>, let go of Alt.
- A Dialog opened; Select the name you chose for the macro and click <kbd>Edit</kbd>

What you got should be a good basis **for further edits** to create a general macro.
Note though that this does not record ALL actions taken, you might need to dig deeper into VBA for details.