# How to filter out some columns in a table?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hi I have a large dataset containing data from:
A1, A2, ..., A12, B1, ..., B12, C1 ... ... H12.

for each column, there are many rows of numbers. I want to sort the data as the following:

A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3 ... H1, H2, H3 (1st dataset)

A4, A5, A6, B4, B5, B6 ... H4, H5, H6 (2nd dataset)

...

A10, A11, A12, B10, B11, B12 ... H10, H11, H12 (8th dataset)

For each sorted dataset, I want it to be in a new sheet.

How can I do this? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/859582/346288 - a way to help yourself.

Comment: Better [edit] the post and avoid the DOWN VOTES to close the post & make clear all about your real need,,,, since the attached screen shot is different than what you have written,,,, !!

Comment: Other than posting here, what have you tried so far and where are you getting stuck? If you are looking for a place to start you need to provide an example of your end result. You also need to get your definitions accurate as filter and sort are two different type of operations. Depending on the structure of your data, those operations may not even be relevant. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

For a one-time operation :

- To select entire columns, click their headers while the
  cursor is a down-pointing arrow. You might need to move the
  cursor a bit until it becomes this arrow. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
  to add columns to the selection, and you may also swipe through
  a range of columns to select it.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the selected columns
- Create a new, click inside the first column and cell and
  press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste.

For a repeated operation, you may record the above operation
as a macro. For information, you may start with Microsoft's
[Quick start: Create a macro](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/quick-start-create-a-macro-741130ca-080d-49f5-9471-1e5fb3d581a8).

An alternative method is to create a VBA macro. See for
example the post
[Using VBA to Copy and Paste Columns to New sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68535163/using-vba-to-copy-and-paste-columns-to-new-sheet).
(Note that VBA is not an easy language to learn.)